# Extending Sentry 2 Models from a Base Eloquent class

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, laravel-4, eloquent

Currently i have all my models extending a base class called **"Base"**

**Base** extends Eloquent

the problem is i use Sentry 2 for user authentication and groups thus my two of my models **User** and **Group** extend their respective Sentry base model **SentryUserModel** and **SentryGroupModel**.

I cannot figure out a way to have these two models: **User, Group** extend my **Base** model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make your User and Group models extend SentryUserModel and SentryGroupModel respectively then extend Base model using a magic function.

**Code:**

```
class User extends SentryUserModel
{
      private $base;

      function __construct()
      {
          $this->base = new Base();
      }

      // fake "extends Base" using magic function
      public function __call($method, $args)
      {
          $this->base->$method($args[0]);
      }        
}


class Group extends SentryGroupModel
{
      private $base;

      function __construct()
      {
          $this->base = new Base();
      }

      // fake "extends Base" using magic function
      public function __call($method, $args)
      {
          $this->base->$method($args[0]);
      }        
}
```